# How to remove space(including tabs) in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, string, replace, tabs

I tried using the following code but it just wouldn't work

```
def output_without_whitespace(phrase):
    phrase = phrase.replace(' ','')
    new_phrase = phrase.replace("\t","")
    return new_phrase
```

for the following phrase: "The fox  \tjumped over the log.   "
the output would be: "Thefox\tjumpedoverthelog."

How do I get rid of the tab?

Comment: Your function works correctly. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your function should work fine and it is a nice way to get the job done. There are other ways for us to rid of white spaces. This is my favourite one:

```
import string
s = '  Hello  World! I   am  Luis !\t\n\r\tHi There  '
s.translate({ord(c): None for c in string.whitespace})
```

You can also use regex. Please take a look [here](https://www.journaldev.com/23763/python-remove-spaces-from-string) for more info.